# Castle Windsor Component registration of multiple interface on a single service

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, ioc-container

i am trying to implement multiple Service Contracts via a single WCF.

i am trying to run this code:

```
  return new WindsorContainer()
            .AddFacility<WcfFacility>()
            .Register(
                Component.For<IServiceBehavior>().Instance(metadata),
                Component.For<IServiceBehavior>().Instance(debug),
                Component
                    .For<IBlogService>()
                    .ImplementedBy<DefaultBlogService>()
                    .Named("blogService")
                    .LifeStyle.Transient
                    .ActAs(new DefaultServiceModel().Hosted()
                        .AddEndpoints(
                            WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new BasicHttpBinding()))),
                Component
                    .For<IBlogServiceAlternate>()
                    .ImplementedBy<AlternateBlogService>()
                    .Named("blogService")
                    .LifeStyle.Transient
                    .ActAs(new DefaultServiceModel().Hosted()
                        .AddEndpoints(
                            WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new BasicHttpBinding()))),


                Component
                    .For<ILogger>()
                    .ImplementedBy<DefaultLogger>()
                    .LifeStyle.Transient
            );
```

but it tells me that the "blogservice" is already registered.
i am loading 2 differant Interfaces which are implemented via differant classes.
and i got stuck in this point.

Answer (score 15):

Just write

```
Component.For<IFirst,ISecond>(). /*whatever else you need*/
```

Comment: yeah i tried that, but the problem is that if i write 
Component.For<IFirst,ISecond>(). 
i cant have ImplementedBy<First,Second> 
or can i?

Answer (score 1):

You are in fact registering IBlogService and IBlogServiceAlternate with the same Name(d) - blogService, therefore the error.

Comment: i know that, and i am doing it on purpose, the idea is to register both Interfaces to the same service.

just like we could do, in case we have 2 ServiceContacts.
that we would like to connect to the same service.